# how to structure solution to allow for multiple data sources for a repository

Tags: c#, .net, rest, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

**How can I structure my solution in order to allow multiple data sources for the same repository?**

I am currently reviewing the [pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=patterns-library&author=scott-allen&name=pattern-repository&clip=7&mode=live):

[image]

My `employee` entity has multiple data sources, such as a sql server database as well as a CRM instance.

**Does the repository pattern allow for multiple data sources for the same repository?**

In my case, I would like to abstract the repository access to the Employee entity by wrapping an Employee repository around it, but I am not sure if I'm implementing an anti-pattern by requiring multiple data sources for the same repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the repository pattern allow for multiple data sources for the same repository?

The repository pattern is just a good practices to segregate the data sources from the remainder of your code. See it like *an advice* to have a loosely coupled implementation. There is no rule of this pattern afterwards: you are free to implement it as you wish, as long as you don't leak the way you get the data from.

> I am not sure if I'm implementing an anti-pattern by requiring multiple data sources for the same repository.

It is not! Think like your repository will handle of the plumbing to manage your employees. This would prevent other developers (and even you once the code base grows) to think to call all the ten different API to properly synchronize all your data sources for a single entity. Thus, you can safely rely on one single class that has the responsibility to save your employees to all the good locations.

> How can I structure my solution in order to allow multiple data sources for the same repository?

That's the funny part, as a developer - the moment when you need to think to an implementation! :) In all the cases, I highly recommend a SOLID approach. That will help you a lot when you are going to add or even edit your solution. Let's imagine we have a contract for the repository.

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
   void Save(Employee employee);
}
```

The implementation can be a main repository that coordinates the *Save* operation. For example, We need to update the employee in the CRM and in the database. We can have two different implementations, so we respect the single responsibility principle:

```
internal class CrmEmployeeRepository
{
   void Save(Employee employee)
   {
      // Using a Web API...
   }
}

internal class DbEmployeeRepository
{
   void Save(Employee employee)
   {
      // Using Entity Framework...
   }
}
```

Note that the two classes have a scope of `ìnternal`. This is because we don't want to expose those implementations to our developers. They need a single API to save an employee. This is because we create an agregator of repository. This is the public API (the one exposed to the developers). This approach respects the single responsibility principle as well, as this implementation only coordinates the other repositories.

```
public class AgregateEmployeeRepository
{
   private IEnumerable<IEmployeeRepository> _repositories;

   public AgregateEmployeeRepository(...)
   {
      // Can be injected manually or with an IoC...
   }

   void Save(Employee employee)
   {
      foreach(IEmployeeRepository repo in _repositories)
      {
         _repos.save(employee);
      }
   }
}
```

Nonetheless, each implementation comes with pros and cons. A typical drawback here is that if a repository throws an exception, the data sources won't be aligned anymore. There are tons of other approaches, such as the asynchronous one, where a separate job processes the updates and controls the exception, enabling to reprocess any record in error. It depends the time you can spend on it and how much this is critical for your business.